# Tikz node anchor and alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, alignment, anchor

In `tikz`, I have a `node` with specified `text width`, so the text can break into multiple lines. I also have another circle with some text in it.

I want the circle to be aligned as in the second picture, but when the text contains multiple lines I want it to remain aligned to the center of the first line.

[image]

**HERE THE CODE**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=blue!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=mid east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Text in the node}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=blue!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Text in the node}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=blue!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Node with very very very very very very long text}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I use `anchor=mid east` the circle moves a little bit right, since the node is anchored to the height of `x`, while `inner sep` considers the height of uppercase letters. If I use `anchor=east` everything works fine unless the node has more than one line. I want to find a solution that works even if I change the font or the font size in the node, without modifying the parameters every time.

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked your code a bit by adding "anchor=base east" to the text node, and that seems to do what I think you are asking to do (I think). New nodes are in red just to differentiate from your originals.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=blue!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=mid east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Text in the node}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=blue!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Text in the node}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=blue!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Node with very very very very very very long text}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=red!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=base east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Node with very very very very very very long text}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \node[white, text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,rotate=90, fill=red!80!black, inner sep=2.2ex, anchor=base east]at (0,0){\vphantom{X}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.4ex\relax}{Node with normal text}};
    \node[anchor=center,white] at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
    \draw[white](0,0) --(0,-\paperwidth);
    \draw[white]  (0,-1.5*2.2ex) circle (2.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the circle is on the right edge in your code. My second is the right example. My problem is only when you have multiple lines (third one): I want the circle to be aligned to the center of the first line exactly as in the second original node.

Comment: Hmm, `[xshift={\dimexpr 0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox}]`  To do it right one would have to `\vsplit` off the first line, `\unvbox` to restore the height, then measure the height and depth.  Otherwise lower case and no descenders may mess things up.

Comment: Does it help to change `(0,0)` to `(1ex,0ex)` as the position of the node that is anchored at base east?

Answer (score 1):

You could experiment with

```
                text height=1.75ex,
                text depth=.5ex,
                minimum height=8ex
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    mult/.style={draw, white, circle, minimum size=6mm,}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
            {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
                    \node[
                    white, 
                    text width=.8\paperheight-4.4ex,
                    rotate=90, 
                    fill=blue!80!black, 
                    inner sep=2.2ex, 
                    anchor=east, 
%                   text height=1.75ex,
                    text depth=.1ex,
                    minimum height=8ex
                    ](q)
                    at 
                    (0,0){{Text in the\\ node}};
                    \node[mult, anchor=center, ](p) at (0,-1.5*2.2ex) {1};
                    \draw[ white] (q.east) -- (q.west);
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        \end{minipage}%
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```